# Set TextView value inside a thread in android

Tags: java, android, xml, multithreading, crash

I am getting a crash under the fllowing circumstances. I am running a thread in the following way:

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run() {    
            text.setText("hello");    
    }
};
t.start;
```

The crash occurs if I try to set the value of a `TextView` in my xml, (the reference to text is already available).

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Kindly point out where am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can only access user interface components from the UI thread.

Android has a few things to make this easy, such as the method [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and the class [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

For more reading see [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) and [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should access android ui toolkit widgets only on the UI thread. Read http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html.

Answer (score 0):

use Handler class and check it for more relevant methods

```
Handler mHandler;
 mHandler=new Handler(){
hdandleMessage(Message what){

text.setText("hello");

}

};
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run()
    {

           mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(int what)

        }
};
t.start;
```